# Motherboard Compatibility - ASUS TUF Z390M-PRO

Tags: compatibility, motherboard

I'm taking the leap and ditching Windows for my own PC as well as my whole family. But whether Ubuntu 19.10 is compatible with the hardware is now an issue.

So far, I've run the live version on 3 builds and installed on 2 of them.
Third one is happening tomorrow.

However, for one family member.. a whole new system needs to be built.

The specs are:

- CPU: i5-9400    [intel doc says linux is supported]
- RAM: 16 GB corsair Vengeance LPX Black  [never heard of ram being a problem]
- card reader: Icy Box IB-868-B [shouldn't be a problem I'm guessing]
- SSD: 500GB crucial P1 M.2  [also shouldn't be a problem]
- Bluray: LG 16x sata [I have a very similar model that works fine under 19.10]
- wifi: ASUS PCE-AC55BT [drivers are already in the 19.10 build]
- monitor: ASUS VP248H [I've got an older version of the same and it is fine]
  camera: Logitech C920 Pro HD [forums seem to indicate it is ok]

But......

- mobo: ASUS S1151 MICROATX TUF z390M- Pro Gaming  (no wifi)
  is what is giving me the grief.. I can't find any info anywhere.
  Asus advertises Windows 10 compatibility, but that is it.

I can't run a live version because the system has to be ordered and built & then it is too late.

Has anyone successfully installed on this motherboard?

Comment: I see no reason why you may have problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Linux Status Report for ASUS Desktop Motherboards](https://dlcdnimgs.asus.com/websites/global/aboutASUS/OS/Linux-Status-report-201810.pdf) the ASUS TUF Z390M-PRO GAMING is tested as compatible with Ubuntu 18.04. It is listed in the ASUS motherboard report as TUF Z390M-PRO GAMING.

Comment: Thanks karel. Sorry about the delay getting back.. many hours into the conversion & I even have to add a vm for all the stuff not supported in Ubuntu.

Comment: How do I mark this as solved?